# DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled while the use of ReadAllLines C#

Tags: c#, directory, streamreader, file.readalllines

[image: The folder the .txt-file is in]

The following piece of code is the code used to call the `.txt-file` and turn it into strings.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\This PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test_read_txt\bin\Debug\read.txt");
```

Why wont C# recognize the location of the `.txt-file`? 
I tried with `StreamReader` but then the read could not be modified.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Define our one and only variable
        string[] M = new string[13];

        // Read the text from the text file, and insert it into the array
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"read.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            M[i] = SR.ReadLine();
        }

        // Close the text file, so other applications/processes can use it
        SR.Close();

        // Write the array to the Console

        Console.WriteLine("The array from the txt.file: ");


        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(M[i]); // Displays the line to the user
        }

        // Pause the application so the user can read the information on the screen
        Console.ReadLine();

        if (2 == 2)
        {
            M[1][1] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

It did not recognize `M[1][1]` as the second element of the second array because it only read the file and did not transform it into a multidimensional array. Can the following code be used for the above described problem?

```
tring[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\This PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test_read_txt\bin\Debug\read.txt");
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `test_read_txt` from your path.  From the screenshot, there are two folders in the path with that name and you are only including one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As users have stated, "This PC" is simply a display path, not a real one.

Try using this instead:

```
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), @"Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test_read_txt\bin\Debug\read.txt");
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Comment: I see, then set the "path" variable to the full path. E.g. `C:\Users\{User}\Documents\...etc`

Comment: And if the text file is in the same folder as the .exe, you can just do `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt")`

Answer (score 2):

"C:\This PC\Documents" is a display path only (in so much as it doesn't physically exist), this actually equates to "C:\Users\{username}\Documents"

Answer (score 2):

C:\This PC\Documents is not the correct path

The easiest way to get the correct file path is
Go to Properties of file > Security > Object name